# Getting three of a kind in a game of yahtzee

Tags: probability

A.I am trying to calculate getting three of a kind in a game of yahthzee but I am not sure what I am doing wrong.
So we have five tossed dices so our possible outcomes are $6*6*6*6*6=7776$ We then have the form of three of a kind $AAABC$ where A can be chosen 6 different ways, B 5 DIFFERENT WAYS ,and C 4 different ways.

then since you have $5C3$ WAYS TO place A $2C1$ WAY TO PLACE B AND $1C1$ WAYS to place C.So then
you multiply $6*5*4*10*2=2400$ so you get three of kind is $\frac{2400}{7776}$

But the correct answer is $25/162$ so I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

B. MY second question is how to get two of a pair. So you have AABBC so you have 6 ways pick A if will be  ,5 ways to pick B, 4 ways to pick c. Then $5C2$ WAYS TO PICK where to place A ,$3C2$ TO PICK where to place B. Two of pair would be $(2,2,1,3,3)$ for example.
SO YOU GET

$6*5*4*10*3=3600$ so two a pair has probability $3600/7776$ but my book says $25/108$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A.You are counting $66653$ as different from $66635$, which makes you a factor $2$ off.

B.You are counting $66553$ as different from $55663$, which makes you a factor $2$ off.

When you have two numbers that are in the same quantity, the same roll can come from picking one first and then the other or from picking the other first.  Go through your calculation and you will see that you count these examples twice.

Comment: So for three of a kind it does not really matter where the BC are placed in AAABC its more about the A

Comment: It does matter, but once you have picked $A$ to be $6$ and placed it in the first three places, you count one case where you pick $B$ to be $5$ and place it fourth, then pick $C$ to be $3$ and a second case where you pick $B$ to be $3$ and place it fifth, then pick $C$ to be $5$.  Both of them give $66653$.

Comment: I see so I have to divide my calculation by 2 because the outcomes of 66653 is the same as 66635 in the game of yahtzee. But I could also have 65636 and 63656. Hmm but I think I get it.

Comment: When you said there were $6^5$ outcomes of rolling the dice, you said order mattered, so 66653 is not the same as 66635.  That is fine as long as you are consistent.  You have counted two ways of making 66653, one where $B=5$ and one where $B=3$.  That is where the factor $2$ comes from.

Comment: I see so in a way you are counting 66653 twice I think I get it ,its kind of a subtle thing

Answer (score 1):

You have $6^5$ total outcomes. To get 3 of one type, you need to calculate $\binom{6}{1}\binom{5}{3}\times 5 \times 4$: 6 choices for the number of 'kind', $\binom{5}{3}$ ways to allocate them, 5 choices for the first and 4 for the second. This last step is because, e.g. $3,4$ and $4,3$ must be counted as different outcomes.

Comment: But cant you have 2 ways to allocate the first where you have 5 choices????

Comment: I'm sorry I don't quite understand what you mean